# while loop and callback return different results

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, while-loop

I have a while loop that matches a condition to filter data from mongodb. However, when I use the callback I only receive one result to the `console.log`. If I console.log inside the while loop, I should receive three entries. Why is only one piece of data making it to the callback?

```
while(i--) {
  if (0 >= [friday, saturday, sunday].indexOf(results[i].selectedDate)) {
      theWeekend = results[i];
      console.log(theWeekend); //returns three results (correct)
    }
}
callback(err, theWeekend)
console.log(theWeekend); //returns one results (incorrect)
```

Correct data

```
{ _id: 56fffb5ceb76276c8f39e3f3,
  url: 'http://londonist.com/2015/11/where-to-eat-and-drink-in-balham',
  title: 'Where To Eat And Drink In... Balham  | Londonist',
  selectedDate: Fri Apr 01 2016 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST),
  __v: 0 }
{ _id: 56fffb8eeb76276c8f39e3f5,
  url: 'https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11404770',
  title: 'The Trouble with CloudFlare | Hacker News',
  selectedDate: Sun Apr 03 2016 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST),
  __v: 0 }
{ _id: 56fffb6ceb76276c8f39e3f4,
  url: 'http://wellnessmama.com/13700/benefits-coconut-oil-pets/',
  title: 'Benefits of Coconut Oil for Pets - Wellness Mama',
  selectedDate: Sat Apr 02 2016 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST),
  __v: 0 }
```

Incorrect data

```
{ _id: 56fffb6ceb76276c8f39e3f4,
  url: 'http://wellnessmama.com/13700/benefits-coconut-oil-pets/',
  title: 'Benefits of Coconut Oil for Pets - Wellness Mama',
  selectedDate: Sat Apr 02 2016 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST),
  __v: 0 }
```

Comment: [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an array to store all the results as follows:

```
var theWeekends = []
while(i--) {
  if (0 >= [friday, saturday, sunday].indexOf(results[i].selectedDate)) {
      theWeekends.push(results[i]);

    }
}
callback(err, theWeekends)
console.log(theWeekends); //returns 3 results (correct)
```